# Varnish with Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cache, varnish

I have Debian 8 with PHP 5.6 installed on my server. I recently installed Magento 2.0.2 and also successfully installed varnish-4.0.2 to use it as a cache on my web server.

I tried to configure varnish-4.0.2 with magento 2 but unfortunately, I'm getting failed every time. The reason why I am saying this because varnish is giving no such performance as compared to I previously experienced with Magento 1.9.2.3. Can anyone please guide me with proper configuration and installation of varnish with magento 2?

Comment: any errors or headers info??

Comment: Have you checked the official documentation? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish.html Also how do you know it's not performing better? Do you have anything to back up this affirmation or is just an opinion?

Comment: @MagenX No errors but the load time is still the same with or without varnish.

Comment: @mbalparda when I use same varnish installation with Magento 1.x, it is working great and also giving my application a boost. But when I am using it with Magento 2, the load time is same also I checked it from tools.pingdom.com

Comment: Follow [these instructions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-final.html) to make sure Varnish is caching content.

Comment: I have just installed & configured Varnish in Ubuntu 14.0.4, may be this can help you too - http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/install-configure-varnish-cache-magento-2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Admin panel -> Configuration -> Full Page Cache -> Varnish Configuration:
Use following settings:

- Caching Application: Varnish Caching
- TTL for public content: 86400
- Access list: localhost
- Backend host: IP of Varnish Server
- Backend port: Public Port of Varnish Server

Hope this will help...

Comment: From docs https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-magento.html looks like "Backend host" is the name varnish uses to iddentify the backend pool